# Is it possible to show subtitles on embbeded youtube videos only when available?

Tags: html, youtube

I'm searching for a way to show subtitles on you tube embedded videos but only if they are available in a certain language. So if they are not available for that specific language I don't have to show any caption.

I am currently using an iframe tag with the following src attribute:

```
<iframe src="embeddedVideoUrl?enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&autoplay=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&nologo=1&rel=0&loop=1&hl=es&cc_lang_pref=en&cc_load_policy=1&playsinline=1"></iframe>
```

Thanks